# Change root directory in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with changing the root directory in .htaccess.

My folder structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDnuH.png).

What I want to achieve is, when I visit this page:

/comparty/about/

The page I will see is this page:

/comparty/pages/about/

I have already tried to search on Google, but the code I found did not work, though I tried to change it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /comparty/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

I don't want it to redirect, I want to keep the same URL. Also I've had a big problem with Apache caching the .htaccess file, so I haven't been able to test many things.

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

I found a way to rewrite the URL from /comparty/pages/about/ to /comparty/about/ - this is the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /comparty/
RewriteRule ^about/(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

This only works on the about page, though. What would I have to do, to make it dynamic and work with every page?

Comment: What is in your current `.htaccess` file?

Comment: The code above is what is in my .htaccess file :)

Comment: Is that file in the `comparty` directory? And is `pages` a directory? If so, is there an `.htaccess` there? If there isn't one, what is there?

Comment: This is how it all looks: http://i.imgur.com/MUfhnLF.png

Comment: I actually got something to work. The question has been edited with the new code.

Comment: So sorry - shouldn't have asked my last questions. Long day, so forgot about your directory structure. Better to post those as text next time. Images in SO are not recommended unless truly necessary anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a dynmic pattern :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /comparty/
#if the request is not for an existent dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#and the request is not for an existent file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#rewrite the request to "/pages/request"
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pages/$1 [L]
```

RewriteConditions above are important to avoid rewriting your existent files and directories to the /pages subfolder. Without those conditionrt the Rule will rewrite all requests including the destination path /pages and this may result in rewrite loop error.

Comment: Thank you so much! But how do I make it work for the index.php page aswell? Right now when I visit /comparty/ it just shows the directory.

Comment: Hello again @starkeen - I have another question. If I visit for example /comparty/about/qwerty/ (the "qwerty" sub folder doesn't exist), I get a "500 Internal Server Error". Is this caused by some loop when rewriting? What can I do to fix it? Thanks in advance.